# How to use NavigationLink outside of NavigationStack?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a safe area inset view that is placed on my `NavigationStack` so that acts as a bottom bar across all pushed views. However, in the safe area inset view, there are button which I'd like to push views onto the stack. The `NavigationLink` is greyed out though since it is outside of a `NavigationStack`.

This is what my code looks like:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            NavigationLink("Button 1") {
                Text("Screen 1")
            }
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            NavigationLink("Button 2") {
                Text("Screen 2")
            }
        }
    }
}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
    HStack {
        NavigationLink("Button 1") {
            Text("Screen 1")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        NavigationLink("Button 2") {
            Text("Screen 2")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .padding()
    .background(.regularMaterial)
}
```

It behaves in a way where the bottom view does indeed stick across all pushed views, but the buttons there do not do anything (the ones in the top navigation bar work properly though):

[image]

How can I get the buttons in the bottom safe area inset to navigation to different screens while still keeping it on the `NavigationStack` level since I do not want to place this bottom overlay code on each sub view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use programmatic navigation with `NavigationStack`:

The state var `navigationPath` holds the active path and you can change it either with `NavigationLink(value:)` or by setting it directly (like in the safe area buttons).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // holds the active navigation path
    @State private var navigationPath: [Int] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath ) {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            // defines destinations of path
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self, destination: { value in
                switch value {
                case 1: Text("Screen 1")
                case 2: Text("Screen 2")
                default: Text("unknown view")
                }
            })
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    NavigationLink("Button 1", value: 1)
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    NavigationLink("Button 2", value: 2)
                }
            }
        }
        
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Button("Button 1") {
                    navigationPath = [1]
                    // or if you want to extend the path:
                    // navigationPath.append(1)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Button("Button 2") {
                    navigationPath = [2]
                    // or if you want to extend the path:
                    // navigationPath.append(2)
               }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.regularMaterial)
        }
    }
}
```